# Tensorflow: Dataset.from_generate() ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

## **Goal**

I want to use tensor as part of input in the dataset.from_generator method.

## **Error Message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 157, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 391, in generator_py_func
    nest.flatten_up_to(output_types, values), flattened_types)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 390, in <listcomp>
    for ret, dtype in zip(

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 124, in _convert
    result = np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype, order="C")

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.


     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT64], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_150"](arg0)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_22 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator_22)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

## **Error Reproduce**

if you replace the definition of `b=tf.ones...` with `b = np.rand..`,the error will disappear.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def _create_generator():
    for i in range(3):
        a = np.random.randn(3,2)
        b = tf.ones([1],tf.float32)
        #b= np.random.randn(1)
        result = {}
        result['a'] =  a
        result['b'] = b
        yield result


gen = _create_generator()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset().from_generator(_create_generator,
                        output_shapes={'a':None,'b':None},
                        output_types ={'a':tf.float32, 'b':tf.float32}).batch(1)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features = iterator.get_next()


init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(features))
```

## Why do I have to use tensor as input

Well, This is because my real program needs to use the output of another tf.data.Dataset as part of the Input(data is stored in format of TFRecords). So it will raise exact the same error as you will see after running this snippet of code. Right now I don't have any idea to make around and fix this problem indirectly(without using tensor as input).

## **Why I need to use Dataset.from_generator**

There is a hack to use estimator.predict() without loading the graph every times you call it, which is to use generator to keep the entry open and it will presume you have not done with 'single' prediction. Then Tensorflow won't load the model graph again and again.

---

If you need more bg info about my info. let me know it. Thank you!

Edit1:

## **Why I have to use Dataset API**

The data volume is huge and originally saved on `hdfs`. So the pipeline was processed in Spark and saved in format of `TFRecord`. And as far as I know I can only use `Dataset` api to restore my data here(also kind of considering the performance here).

Comment: ... what are you trying to do with `estimator.predict` that requires you to call it multiple times?

Comment: @DomJack This is because my model is for Reinforcement learning. I need to interact with environment step by step. So let's say I want my actor to make decisions 100 times, it's necessary to call `.predict` hundred times either.

Comment: Do you need to use `predict` for that? Can you use `tf.py_func` on your agent output rather than a generator part-way through?

Comment: I get confused on your guidance. I got a deep learning model in form of `estimator`. But how can I wrap the whole thing in a single function to do the prediction without using the `.predict` api of estimator?

Answer (score 1):

Furthering discussion from comments, `Estimator.predict` isn't doing anything magical. There's admittedly some fancy stuff - mostly for running in parallel across multiple GPUs - but you can always construct the graph manually via `Estimator.model_fn`:

```
estimator = get_estimator()           # however you generate it
features, labels = input_fn()         # whatever you would use with `predict`
mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT  # or TRAIN/EVAL
# depending on your estimator, you may not need mode/config args
spec = estimator.model_fn(features, labels, mode, config=None)
# spec is a tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec - a named tuple
predictions = spec.predictions
# you might have to flatten the function inputs/outputs/Tout below
next_features = tf.py_func(
    next_features_fn, predictions, Tout={'a': tf.float32, 'b': tf.float32})
```

Comment: Wow I do not know I can use it like this,  in this case, `next_features_fn` will serve as `input_fn` in the traditional usage of `estimator.predict`? And I need to place my generator there?

Comment: But if that's the case, it may not rescue me here? Because my rub here should derive from the `Dataset.from_generator`, which is inside the `input_fn`.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `Dataset` API? I'm guessing your python function represents the environments response to your agents actions?

Comment: See Edit1 for more infos on my situation.

Comment: Why did you switch from hdf5 to tfrecords? As far as I'm aware, tfrecords aren't designed for efficient storage (rather, fast reads), but I'm also not aware of a way to read a random record. I'm not saying there -is- no way - just that I don't know what it is, and I'd be surprised if it was significantly faster than something like hdf5.

Comment: Well I have to say I do not consider thoroughly on performance of these two. The reasons I choose `TFrecord` at the beginning are: 1. There exists many tutorials on tensorflow using the 'TFrecord' format and also recommend it, so I think it should be some gains using that format. 2. My data contain `Varlen` variable. `Tfrecord` method provide good api to take care of them. (`tf.VarLen`.. etc.)

Comment: I'm confident you'd see no performance penalty with TFRecords when using them as intended - i.e. as part of an input pipeline. I suspect -most- of this performance gain is for multiple GPU parallelization though. I've never noticed a difference myself between them and using `Dataset.map` through a `tf.py_func`. I don't think this usage is what they were designed for though...